# VSTO Outlook Add-in referencing external libraries fails

Tags: deployment, outlook, vsto, add-in

I'm working on a VSTO add-in for Outlook, versions 2007-2013and minimum .Net version is 4.0.  In my project I have a couple of referenced libraries.  When I deploy the add-in via MSI (built via Wix) the add-in itself is loaded into Outlook but, the referenced libraries are not available.

It works fine on my development machine so I'm assuming it is a trust issue of some sort. I am uncertain as to what needs done to have the included libraries themselves be trusted.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: did you check if machine is running .net framework client profile or full framework

Comment: .Net client framework is what I'm checking for but, the test machine has the full framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using VS setup project for addin deployment? If so, you might want to try

`Right-click setup project icon => Add => Assembly...`

to add your external libraries.

Regarding the trust issue, please take a look at these [articles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb772086.aspx) on MSDN. [Inclusion list](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb608607.aspx) might also be helpful in your case.

Also, to test deployment on your development machine, I'd suggest you clean your project/solution first

`Right-click Project/Solution icon in Solution Explorer => Clean`

then deploy and install your addin onto your machine.

Comment: I'm using Wix 3.7. A Visual Studio installation project does not meet the requirements unfortunately. Cleaning and installing works on the dev machine. I had looked into a custom action using an inclusion list but, after the install worked on the dev box (post clean) I had the assumption it wouldn't be needed.

Comment: To update this, I found the issue.  It was actually a bug in the library occurring because of an input error.  I've had it updated and all seems fine now.

Comment: Oh great! Glad to hear that.